# Output date month in uppercase

Tags: vba, excel

So i have `Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = UCase(Date)` followed by `Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "MMMM"` which outputs the current date and formats it to the current month name but Ucase() doesn't capitalize the name, is it because `Date` is not a string? or because of the formatting `.NumberFormat` afterwords?

Here is part the code:

```
If Not rngColJ Is Nothing Then
    For Each Rng In rngColJ
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = UCase(Format(d, "MMMM"))
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first make a string and the `Ucase()` it.

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim d As Date
    d = Now
    MsgBox UCase(Format(d, "MMM"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! I didn't think of that. I dropped the formatting `Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "MMMM"` and viola :D

Comment: @TomaszKozuch  Good Job!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Which_Month()
Dim A As String

    A = UCase(Format(Date, "mmmm"))
    Debug.Print A
    Msgbox A

End Sub
```